# How do I convert NaN to my original data?

Tags: python, pandas, nan, shapefile

I am trying to do a map that shows economic and unemployment data for each county.  When I reach the point where I merge my excel file with the shapefile data, the data from my excel file is all NaNs.

How do I rectify this?

Here is my code thus far:

Here is a sample of data from the shapefile:

```
        NAME    STATE_NAME  FIPS    geometry
    0   Lake of the Woods   Minnesota   27077   POLYGON ((-95.34283 48.54668, -95.34105 48.715...
    1   Ferry   Washington  53019   POLYGON ((-118.85163 47.94956, -118.84846 48.4...
    2   Stevens Washington  53065   POLYGON ((-117.43883 48.04412, -117.54219 48.0...
    3   Okanogan    Washington  53047   POLYGON ((-118.97209 47.93915, -118.97406 47.9...
    4   Pend Oreille    Washington  53051   POLYGON ((-117.43858 48.99992, -117.03205 48.9...
```

Here is a sample of data from my excel file:

```
        fips    makeup  unemp_15    unemp_19    net_change  main_industry   fossil_fuel
        0   1001    urban   5.2 2.7 -0.6    utilities   yes
        1   1003    urban   5.5 2.7 -0.7    hospitality no
        2   1005    rural   8.9 3.8 -1.3    mining  yes
        3   1007    urban   6.6 3.1 -0.9    construction    no
        4   1009    urban   5.4 2.7 -0.7    manufacturing   no
```

Here is my merging process, and the resultant data:

```
        merged = map_df.set_index('FIPS').join(data_for_map.set_index('fips'))
        ​
        merged.head()
        NAME    STATE_NAME  geometry    makeup  unemp_15    unemp_19    net_change  main_industry   fossil_fuel
        FIPS                                    
        27077   Lake of the Woods   Minnesota   POLYGON ((-95.34283 48.54668, -95.34105 48.715...   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
        53019   Ferry   Washington  POLYGON ((-118.85163 47.94956, -118.84846 48.4...   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
        53065   Stevens Washington  POLYGON ((-117.43883 48.04412, -117.54219 48.0...   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
        53047   Okanogan    Washington  POLYGON ((-118.97209 47.93915, -118.97406 47.9...   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
        53051   Pend Oreille    Washington  POLYGON ((-117.43858 48.99992, -117.03205 48.9...   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Here is my full code thus far:

````
    #Import required libraries
    
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    import geopandas as gpd
    import shapefile as shp
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import seaborn as sns
    #Set the filepath and load in a shapefile
    
    fp = 'C:/Users/timho/UScounties/UScounties.shp'
    map_df = gpd.read_file(fp)
    print (map_df)
                           NAME  STATE_NAME STATE_FIPS CNTY_FIPS   FIPS  \
    0         Lake of the Woods   Minnesota         27       077  27077   
    1                     Ferry  Washington         53       019  53019   
    2                   Stevens  Washington         53       065  53065   
    3                  Okanogan  Washington         53       047  53047   
    4              Pend Oreille  Washington         53       051  53051   
    ...                     ...         ...        ...       ...    ...   
    3136  Skagway-Hoonah-Angoon      Alaska         02       232  02232   
    3137          Yukon-Koyukuk      Alaska         02       290  02290   
    3138    Southeast Fairbanks      Alaska         02       240  02240   
    3139                 Denali      Alaska         02       068  02068   
    3140             Broomfield    Colorado         08       014  08014   
    
                                                   geometry  
    0     POLYGON ((-95.34283 48.54668, -95.34105 48.715...  
    1     POLYGON ((-118.85163 47.94956, -118.84846 48.4...  
    2     POLYGON ((-117.43883 48.04412, -117.54219 48.0...  
    3     POLYGON ((-118.97209 47.93915, -118.97406 47.9...  
    4     POLYGON ((-117.43858 48.99992, -117.03205 48.9...  
    ...                                                 ...  
    3136  MULTIPOLYGON (((-137.80952 58.71648, -137.4674...  
    3137  POLYGON ((-161.04770 62.20469, -160.99428 62.8...  
    3138  POLYGON ((-146.96382 63.46070, -146.95735 64.2...  
    3139  POLYGON ((-152.98947 62.74900, -152.48773 63.1...  
    3140  POLYGON ((-105.05201 39.99761, -104.99139 40.0...  
    
    [3141 rows x 6 columns]
    #Prep Shapefile data
    
    map_df = map_df.drop(columns=["STATE_FIPS", "CNTY_FIPS"])
    map_df.head()
    NAME    STATE_NAME  FIPS    geometry
    0   Lake of the Woods   Minnesota   27077   POLYGON ((-95.34283 48.54668, -95.34105 48.715...
    1   Ferry   Washington  53019   POLYGON ((-118.85163 47.94956, -118.84846 48.4...
    2   Stevens Washington  53065   POLYGON ((-117.43883 48.04412, -117.54219 48.0...
    3   Okanogan    Washington  53047   POLYGON ((-118.97209 47.93915, -118.97406 47.9...
    4   Pend Oreille    Washington  53051   POLYGON ((-117.43858 48.99992, -117.03205 48.9...
    %matplotlib inline
    map_df.plot()
    <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x289acce5e88>
    
    df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/timho/Econ_Plan.csv', header=0)
    df.head()
    fips    state   area_name   urban_or_rural  ue_rate_2015    ue_rate_2016    ue_rate_2017    ue_rate_2018    ue_rate_2019    avg_ue_rate_chg high_ue main_industry   fossil_fuel hhi_2019
    0   1001    AL  Autauga County, AL  urban   5.2 5.1 3.9 3.6 2.7 -0.6    no  utilities   yes 58,233
    1   1003    AL  Baldwin County, AL  urban   5.5 5.3 4.1 3.6 2.7 -0.7    no  hospitality no  59,871
    2   1005    AL  Barbour County, AL  rural   8.9 8.3 5.8 5.1 3.8 -1.3    no  mining  yes 35,972
    3   1007    AL  Bibb County, AL urban   6.6 6.4 4.4 3.9 3.1 -0.9    no  construction    no  47,918
    4   1009    AL  Blount County, AL   urban   5.4 5.4 4.0 3.5 2.7 -0.7    no  manufacturing   no  52,902
    df = df[['fips', 'urban_or_rural', 'ue_rate_2015', 'ue_rate_2019', 'avg_ue_rate_chg', 'main_industry', 'fossil_fuel']]
    data_for_map = df.rename(index=str, columns={'urban_or_rural': 'makeup', 'ue_rate_2015': 'unemp_15', 'ue_rate_2019': 'unemp_19', 'avg_ue_rate_chg': 'net_change'})
    #Check dat dataframe
    
    data_for_map.head()
    fips    makeup  unemp_15    unemp_19    net_change  main_industry   fossil_fuel
    0   1001    urban   5.2 2.7 -0.6    utilities   yes
    1   1003    urban   5.5 2.7 -0.7    hospitality no
    2   1005    rural   8.9 3.8 -1.3    mining  yes
    3   1007    urban   6.6 3.1 -0.9    construction    no
    4   1009    urban   5.4 2.7 -0.7    manufacturing   no
    #Join the geodataframe with the cleaned up csv dataframe
    
    merged = map_df.set_index('FIPS').join(data_for_map.set_index('fips'))
    ​
    merged.head()
    NAME    STATE_NAME  geometry    makeup  unemp_15    unemp_19    net_change  main_industry   fossil_fuel
    FIPS                                    
    27077   Lake of the Woods   Minnesota   POLYGON ((-95.34283 48.54668, -95.34105 48.715...   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
    53019   Ferry   Washington  POLYGON ((-118.85163 47.94956, -118.84846 48.4...   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
    53065   Stevens Washington  POLYGON ((-117.43883 48.04412, -117.54219 48.0...   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
    53047   Okanogan    Washington  POLYGON ((-118.97209 47.93915, -118.97406 47.9...   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
    53051   Pend Oreille    Washington  POLYGON ((-117.43858 48.99992, -117.03205 48.9...   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
    #Set a variable that will call whatever column we want to visualize on the map
    
    variable = 'unemp_19'
    #Set the range for the chloropleth
    
    vmin, vmax = 0, 20
    #Create figure and axes for Matplotlib
    
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(10, 6))
    
    #Create map
    
    merged.plot(column=variable, cmap='Blues', linewidth=0.8, ax=ax, edgecolor='0.8')
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-185-3dd9742880f0> in <module>
    ----> 1 merged.plot(column=variable, cmap='Blues', linewidth=0.8, ax=ax, edgecolor='0.8')
    
    ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geodataframe.py in plot(self, *args, **kwargs)
        604         from there.
        605         """
    --> 606         return plot_dataframe(self, *args, **kwargs)
        607 
        608     plot.__doc__ = plot_dataframe.__doc__
    
    ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopandas\plotting.py in plot_dataframe(df, column, cmap, color, ax, cax, categorical, legend, scheme, k, vmin, vmax, markersize, figsize, legend_kwds, classification_kwds, **style_kwds)
        542         values = np.array(binning.yb)
        543 
    --> 544     mn = values[~np.isnan(values)].min() if vmin is None else vmin
        545     mx = values[~np.isnan(values)].max() if vmax is None else vmax
        546 
    
    ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py in _amin(a, axis, out, keepdims, initial)
         30 def _amin(a, axis=None, out=None, keepdims=False,
         31           initial=_NoValue):
    ---> 32     return umr_minimum(a, axis, None, out, keepdims, initial)
         33 
         34 def _sum(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=False,
    
    ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation minimum which has no identity

​```
````

Comment: Hi Tim, welcome to SO. I see there is a bit of confusion - use backticks (the key in the top row before1 key), not periods for formatting code blocks.

Comment: How did you do this merge?   Show us your code.